# Property Let creates an unwanted variable

Tags: vba, excel, variables, properties

I can't find anything on this anywhere so here's my problem (although it is mostly a cosmetic one):

I have a class being used as a custom data type, but when I look in the locals or watch window I see that each Property Let has created an extra variable, which clutters the window with redundant variables and information (and potentially takes up extra space).

**Example:**

In class module Class1:

```
Private data As Integer

Property Get X() As Integer
    X = data
End Property

Property Let X(ByVal Value As Integer)
    data = Value
End Property
```

And to test:

```
Sub Test1()

Dim TestClass As Class1
Set TestClass = New Class1

TestClass.X = 100

End Sub
```

In the locals window:

[image: locals window]

Am I supposed to be recycling this extra variable somehow or am I doing something else wrong?

--- If you look at stock Excel objects (like a Worksheet) there are no duplicate variables whatsoever.

**Edit:** To clarify, I want to know if there is a way to hide the Property in the locals/watch window to make them easier to navigate.

Comment: Locals window will show all variable created. That is normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine. `data` is your private variable and `X` is just property. Nothing wrong about that. But you should consider naming convention, setters and getters for private variable should be somehow consistent, for example:

```
'Member variable, pName - private Name
Private pName As String

'Properties
Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pName
End Property

Property Let Name(val As String)
    pName = val
End Property
```

Comment: Yeah I do use consistent names usually, I just wanted to clearly demonstrate that two different variables were created. So is there no way to at least hide these in the locals window? It makes debugging more difficult and I'd rather it look cleaner.

Comment: @LeoSteeves Unfortunately, there is now way to get rid out of this. In this window you get all info about object - all private variables and all properties.